# PHP order array by length and then by index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In PHP you can do this to order an array of strings by their size:

```
usort($parts, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
```

How do I order an array of strings by **size** but if two strings are the same size, order them by their **index** in the original array.

eg:

`I a o delicious cake`

becomes:

`delicious cake I a o`

At the moment with my current code it becomes:

`delicious cake o a i`

Comment: check my answer below. I hope it is what you exactly want @BarneyChambers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this method for sort array.

```
<?php
$parts = "I a o delicious cake";
$parts = explode(" ",$parts);
array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $parts),SORT_DESC, $parts); // this is for DESC order
//array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $parts),SORT_ASC, $parts); // you can use this for ASC order
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parts); //return like this "delicious cake I a o"
?>
```

Comment: just did some testing and actually this code doesn't produce correct output

Comment: @BarneyChambers ok give me some time i will find other solution

Comment: But still may be OP not get desired result because he want to sort by index but your solution will sort by value. check your solution with different characters

Comment: I believe this still does not work sorry!  it appears not to always sort by length correctly

Comment: @BarneyChambers please provide me string that causing issue.

Comment: Here is one example: "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccc
dddd eee fff gg hh ii jj kk l." the expected output is "L gg hh ii jj kk eee fff dddd ccccccc
bbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Expected output is like this "L gg hh ii jj kk eee fff dddd ccccccc
bbbbbbbbb aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" Also it is sorted ascending :)

Comment: you want in both order ASC and DESC ?

Comment: @BarneyChambers first clear what you want in your previous example expected result is sorting with descending order of length and in " "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb ccccccc dddd eee fff gg hh ii jj kk l." this example you want length by ascending order

Comment: I still think this code does not work. Example "I love to code" should return "I to love code" but instead it is returning "I to code love"

Answer (score 0):

For sorting with length then index you can use `array_multisort` like below

```
<?php

$str="I love to code";
$parts=explode(" ", $str);

$keys = array_keys($parts);
$values = array_values($parts);

array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $values), SORT_ASC, $keys, SORT_ASC, $parts);

$new_str = implode(" ", $parts);
echo $new_str;
```

demo : https://3v4l.org/BJ1Cl

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead of `usort`.

From the documentation:

> uasort — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and
>   **maintain index association**

The normal `usort` function does not do this:

> If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted
>   array is undefined.

Comment: Sorry xander I dont think this will work, I need it to sorts by length and then by array index